# MVC Linq .Random() wrong syntax

Tags: linq, model-view-controller, random

Hello guys I have some problem with this code but not find something similar in knowledgeBase:

```
@foreach (var prodotti in contesto.Prodotti.Where(x => x.ProdottoVisibile == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProdottoID).Random().Take(5))
```

it seems .Random() is not working, should i have to manage differently ? of course YES, but how?
anyone can give me an tips?
thx a lot!

Comment: What is `Random()` method?  I don't see any on [`Queryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

you can define a variable with your list of records :

```
var prodotti = contesto.Prodotti.Where(x => x.ProdottoVisibile == 
                 true).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProdottoID)
//define Random variable     
var random = new Random();
int index = random.Next(prodotti.Count);    
//This line should return 5 random records from the list 
prodotti.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(5);
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.